# Remove wordpress sticky posts from loop

Tags: wordpress, sticky

Not sure if this is the best way to handle this, but I had a need to remove stick posts from the loop, I still need the sticky to show up on the first page, but since I use an endless list I didn't want it showing up twice. This works, but it feels a bit hackish to edit the index.php file to accomplish it... any other thoughts?

```
//Get the current page number
$url_args=explode('/',trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/'));
$page_number=array_pop($url_args);

$sticky=get_option('sticky_posts');

//if no page number, we are on the home page, so stickies are ok
$print_it=($page_number=='')?true:(in_array(get_the_ID()*1,$sticky)?false:true);
```

an easier to read if statement:

```
if($page_number=='' || !in_array(get_the_ID(),$sticky)) $print_it=true;
else $print_it=false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would use `$page_number = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1` to establish the current page.

I am a little confused about your nested if statements (not the easiest to read!!) but I think this function is a little easier to read and maintain:

```
$print_it=print_it();

function print_it(){
 if($page_number<=1){
   if (!in_array(get_the_ID(),$sticky){
    return true;
   }
 return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: that oughta do it, although the real point was using the `get_query_var`. This will be flexible to permalink structure changes and is easier to read.